# How to point spring boot java app to subdomain?

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

i'm very new to AWS and currently having issues with domain and subdomain for my app. 
I'm trying to host my Java Spring Boot web application as REST API and Angular app as front end on AWS EC2 instance. I want my Angular to run on port and be accessible via example.com and my java app to be accessible via api.example.com.

I've connected domain from godaddy to my Elastic IP already, and created Hosted zone in Route 53 for subdomain and added nameservers to domain on godaddy. Currently i'm waiting for propagation, and I assume that once I run angular on port :80, it will be accessible via example.com.

But how to point java app to **api.example.com** ? 
As spring boot is using embedded tomcat, where should I set up a link between port and subdomain?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to put some kind of reverse proxy in front of your two applications, which will route requests based on hostname (it can be just apache or nginx running on that same host, or [AWS ALB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html))

Comment: @DusanBajic Can u please assist me a bit there? I don't have systemctl \ systemd commands on my ec2 instance, are there other commands to achieve this ( I found them necessary to set up nginx)
Are there other options?